# Filter content of inherited param comments

Tags: xml-documentation, shfb, inheritdoc

I have comments like this:

```
/// <summary>some summary</summary>
/// <param name="a">
///     <para id="0">Comment 0</para>
///     <para id="1">Comment 1</para>
///     <para id="2">Comment 2</para>
/// </param>
/// <param name="b">
///     <para id="1">Comment 3</para>
///     <para id="0">Comment 4</para>
/// </param>
void InterfaceMethod(int a, int b);
```

For the implementing method, I'd like to have the same documentation, but without those paragraphs having `id="0"`, using `inheritdoc`.
How can I author the `inheritdoc` element?

The uncommon use of the `id` attributes in this context shall add the flexibility of not being tied to the order of the paragraphs as they appear in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but it looks cumbersome.

```
/// <summary><inheritdoc/></summary>
/// <param name="a"><inheritdoc select="node()[parent::node()[@name='a'] and @id&gt;0]"/></param>
/// <param name="b"><inheritdoc select="node()[parent::node()[@name='b'] and @id&gt;0]"/></param>
public void InterfaceMethod(int a, int b) { }
```

As [it is not possible to use XPath expressions as a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5200968/806690), the `param` elements must be repeated.
The expression `@id>0` (the `>` needed to be escaped) now selects the intended paragraphs only.

But what about the other markup?
The nested `inheritdoc` element will select the content of *all* `param` nodes, so we must add a condition on the parent's name attribute.

Finally, the `inheritdoc` tag within the `summary` tag will copy the summary. If we placed a `inheritdoc` on root level, this would again select the `param`, as described [here](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/79897974-ffc9-4b84-91a5-e50c66a0221d.htm).